# Export .h defines in .S file

Tags: c, assembly, preprocessor

I have to include some of the macros from .h in .S file. .h includes c declarations as well. Hence I took the defines out using

`gcc -E -dM header.h > generated_header.h`

*generated_header.h* has all predefined macros and standard symbols also.

Now  `gcc -Iinclude/ asm.S -o asm.o`  gives number of following warnings

`warning: "__GCC_ATOMIC_LLONG_LOCK_FREE" redefined
warning: "__GCC_ATOMIC_SHORT_LOCK_FREE" redefined
warning: "__STDC__" redefined`  etc...

This is because we are redefining same macros again by including *generated_header.h* in *asm.S*

I checked all the preprocessor options for extracting only local defines. But nothing helped. Is there any other way to solve this. Is there any other way to make asm.S to be aware of those macros?.

Comment: I had the same problem a few years ago.  What I ended up doing was writing a custom postprocessor that would discard the expanded header after preprocessing.  Super ugly, I know.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is to split the header files into multiple smaller header files, that can be included individually?

Comment: Sounds bad creating multiple header files just for this purpose. It will be a huge pain to include all these header files in case if any .c  needs.

Comment: As a workaround, you can run `-dM` with an empty file to get a list of predefined macros, then run it on your file and filter out the predefined ones.

Comment: @suren99 Another thing you could do is guard all declarations in the header files with `#ifndef __ASSEMBLER__` so they won't get expanded when including the header from an assembly file.

Comment: Then I'd say you have implemented your design wrong. A single source file shouldn't need a single header file that contains *everything*, including macros and structures that other source files might need but not the current one. And if every source file needs everything then perhaps you're structuring the sources wrong? Keep it simple and minimal.

Comment: You could also try to use `-dD` so you don't get the predefined macros.

Comment: What @Someprogrammerdude meant is for each header you already have, split the defines out of it, then have *the header* `#include "foo_defines.h"` so a C program that wants to use it still only has to `#include "foo.h"`.  Yes it would be ugly if the C had to #include 2 headers to make one work, but headers can include other headers.  It does make editing / managing that header slightly more complex, although only defines that are actually needed in asm need to go in the `foo_defines.h` file.

Comment: @fuz  It still shows warning for GCC specific and system specific macros.

Comment: @suren99 No, I mean `-dD` instead of `-dM` to dump the macros from the header.

Comment: @fuz according to [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) -dD  does not include predefined macros.  i just created two files one ran with -dD option enabled and other ran with -dM option enabled. When comparing the difference between files i just see additional few  ARM related #undef (since i am using ARM compiler) on file with -dD enabled. Rest are same. If this is the case then i have to use \__ASSEMBLER__defines on header file as you said or follow @ Some programmer dude solution

Comment: @suren99 Well that's weird.